# How to declare compile options as valid symbols in Flex under IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea

I've got the following Flex code in an MXML file:

```
<mx:Label id="lblVersion" styleName="versionID" bottom="0" right="10" text="Version { BUILD::version }"/>
```

where the "BUILD::version" is meant to be substituted from symbols defined in compiler options:

```
 -define BUILD::version "'LOCAL'"
```

The Flex plugin doesn't seem to understand the compiler option usage syntax and flags "BUILD" and "version" as "unresolved variable or type"

Is there a way around this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer from the IDEA forum:

Symbol definitions ("-define foo::bar" in the FlexBuilder "Additional compiler arguments" should be defined in the "Conditional compilation definitions" field of the IDEA facet (on the Advanced tab).

Conditional compilations definitions ("-define foo::bar") in the "Additional compiler options" field of the IDEA Flex facet are ignored.

Comment: Additionally, it makes a difference whether you have the string definition as -define BUILD::version,"'LOCAL'" instead of  -define BUILD::version,\"LOCAL\". Flex Builder allows both, but IntelliJ seems to only accept the first one.